# Which event to execute if SELECT has only one option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a three chained `select` elements. The first is populated by PHP doing MySQL query and fetching objects. The second is populated depending on first selection by calling `change` event. See code below:

```
$('.form-horizontal').on('change', '#proyectos', function(){
    var id = $('#proyectos').val();

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{{ path('centros') }}",
        dataType:'json',
        data: 'id=' + id,
        success: function(data) {
            var html = "";
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                html += '<option value="'+ index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                $("#centros").html(html);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            request.abort();
        }
    });
});
```

The third is populated based on second `change` value as follow:

```
$('.form-horizontal').on('change', '#centros', function(){
    var id = $('#centros').val();

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "{{ path('unidades') }}",
        dataType:'json',
        data: 'id=' + id,
        success: function(data) {
            var html = "";
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                html += '<option value="'+ index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                $("#unidades").html(html);
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            request.abort();
        }
    });
});
```

If first and second has more than one value my code works perfectly but if for example first select has only one `option` then my code stop working since `change` event is never executed. How I can fix this issue on my code?

Comment: I think this is more of an implementation issue... Either you should always have at least two option (a default dummy "Select an Option" and one real value) OR you need to make sure that the first option of each select is selected on the server side.

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment:  How do you currently make sure that Option 1 of Select 2 is selected on page load?

Comment: If only one option is there, this is selected and you have to execute the change function to show the next select. Normally you should use a placeholder option (i.e. "Please choose")

Comment: @Steve because I wrap all the code in `$(function() { //code here });` which happen when page loads

Comment: @PHPglue this is a Twig sentece and its translate into complete URL for Symfony2 projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Steve suggestions I change my code a bit and now it works, here is the solution:

```
$(function(){
    $('.form-horizontal').on('change', '#proyectos', function(){
        var id = $('#proyectos').val();

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{{ path('centros') }}",
            dataType:'json',
            data: 'id=' + id,
            success: function(data) {
                var html = "<option>---Seleccione una opción---</option>";
                $.each(data, function(index, value){
                    html += '<option value="'+ index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                    $("#centros").html(html);
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                request.abort();
            }
        });
    });

    $('.form-horizontal').on('change', '#centros', function(){
        var id = $('#centros').val();

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{{ path('unidades') }}",
            dataType:'json',
            data: 'id=' + id,
            success: function(data) {
                var html = "<option>---Seleccione una opción---</option>";
                $.each(data, function(index, value){
                    html += '<option value="'+ index + '">' + value + '</option>';
                    $("#unidades").html(html);
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                request.abort();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the event on the ajax's success-event like so:

`if(data.length == 1) $(element).change()`